# How to show Audio Player in UI react-native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, audio, audio-player, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sound

I have number of URLs which getting from server response. And I have to display that in Flatlist, There are number of links. Each Flatlist, I have to show some data and then bottom of the cell needs to show player with progress bar.

[image]

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const sound = new Sound('http://sounds.com/some-sound', null, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    // do something
  }

  // play when loaded
  sound.play();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these packages;

- [react-native-media-controls](https://github.com/charliesbot/react-native-media-controls#readme)
- [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit)